# Required @OA\Info() not found exception in is not working in laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel-8, swagger-ui

i followed: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger but still getting

**ErrorException
Required @OA\Info() not found**
I put @OA\Info() as follows in controller class,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title=" OpenApi Documentation",
 *      description=" Swagger OpenApi description",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="admin@admin.com"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\License(
 *          name="Apache 2.0",
 *          url="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
 *      )
 * )
 *
 * @OA\Server(
 *      url=L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST,
 *      description=" API Server"
 * )

 *
 * @OA\Tag(
 *     name="Projects",
 *     description=" Api Endpoints"
 * )
 * @OA\Schemes(format="http")
 * @OAS\SecurityScheme(
 *      securityScheme="bearer_token",
 *      type="http",
 *      scheme="bearer"
 * )
 */
}
```

where am i being wrong ?

Comment: Your code seems fine

Comment: try adding the `@OA\Info` annotation outside the class, like below the `use` statements but before the `class` definition

Comment: @JeffPuckett its not working

Comment: same here. can't find solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title=" OpenApi Documentation",
 *      description=" Swagger OpenApi description",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="admin@admin.com"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\License(
 *          name="Apache 2.0",
 *          url="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
 *      )
 * )
 *
 * @OA\Server(
 *      url=L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST,
 *      description=" API Server"
 * )

 *
 * @OA\Tag(
 *     name="Projects",
 *     description=" Api Endpoints"
 * )
 * @OA\Schemes(format="http")
 * @OAS\SecurityScheme(
 *      securityScheme="bearer_token",
 *      type="http",
 *      scheme="bearer"
 * )
 */
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```